# Switch inside a switch loop ... what is wrong with my code?

Tags: php

Ok guys, i´m trying to switch inside a case but it does not work it allways falls back to the default. What am i missing?
When i try /index.php?siteSettings it displays the default, same thing when i try index.php?siteSettings&mode=adminSettings

```
switch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']){

    case 'logout':
        include("logout.php");
        break;

    case 'siteSettings':

        switch($_GET['mode']){

            case 'generalSettings':
                $mainPageTitle = "General settings";
                $caseFile = "".$admin_templates_path."/generalSettings.php";
                break;

            case 'adminSettings':
                $mainPageTitle = "Admin settings";
                $caseFile = "".$admin_templates_path."/adminSettings.php";
                break;

            case 'userSettings':
                $mainPageTitle = "User settings";
                $caseFile = "".$admin_templates_path."/userSettings.php";
                break;

            case 'advertising':
                $mainPageTitle = "Advertising";
                $caseFile = "".$admin_templates_path."/advertising.php";
                break;

            default:
                $mainPageTitle = "General settings";
                $caseFile = "".$admin_templates_path."/generalSettings.php";
                break;


        }
        break;
    default:
        $mainPageTitle = "General settings";
        $caseFile = "".$admin_templates_path."/generalSettings.php";
        break;

}
```

Comment: You'll want to break out the query string, or pass the site page in differently. `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` will equal `siteSettings&mode=adminSettings`, so will fall back to the default.

Comment: why would you want a switch inside a switch?

Comment: It works, i don´t know what was i thinking. Thank ou very much. Now i did explode the QUERY_STRING and can access the part i need.

Comment: because i create my own templates so i will need other submenus on the selected 
 page. I could not think of a better way to do this other then switches only if else $_GET but i rather not.

Comment: Have a look at the MVC pattern. You should have individual scripts for each settings screen, etc.

Answer (score 1):

After @aynber made me aware of my mistake this is what i did and it does work now.

Maybe someone will need it.

Thnx guys.

```
$switchPage = explode("~",str_replace(["?","&","="], "~",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));

switch($switchPage[0]){
.....
```